# Alterar seleção da Guia(Aba) no Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome

Pesquisei um tanto, e não encontrei alternativas para a questão.
Queria saber se é possível em `JavaScript` ou `PHP` alterar a aba selecionada no Chrome.
Por exemplo há uma ferramenta que realiza extrações `.csv` periódicas executando links em novas guias que se fecham automaticamente.
9 novas guias são abertas, gostaria que após a solicitação de abertura o Chrome voltasse a primeira Guia.

Pensei em simular o pressionamento(9*) das teclas `CTRL+Page UP` mas não achei nada concreto para que isso funcione.

Utilizar alguma API do chrome para selecionar a guia `Tab[1]`.

Caso haja alguma sugestão fico no aguardo!

Comment: Porque precisa usar o Chrome? A pergunta não está clara, se estiver utilizando algum plugin/extensão no Chrome isso pode ser possível, talvez criar uma extensão para isso (?). Agora com apenas Javascript acredito que seja impossível uma janela 'dizer para o chrome tornar a outra janela ativa'.

Comment: A página contém um dashboard desenvolvido para o chrome! Vou dar uma pesquisada em extenção vi uma com nome de Tabs Revolver que fazia algo parecido.

Comment: A dashboard foi criada por você ou está consumindo uma já criada, querendo automatizar as extrações dos `.csv`? Se for o segundo não vejo motivo para usar o Chrome, pode utilizar o webdriver ou até mesmo o CURL para baixar os dados, sem necessidade de um navegador.